# sql - split first and last name

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2016

I need to split all names into first and last.

I have the names in the same column and the names have several words.
For example

```
table1

Nome
____________________________________
Abel da Silva Barros                                   
Abel da Silva Dias                                     
Abilio Rodrigo Garcia da Silva Costa                   
Adelino David Oliveira Silva                           
Ademar Adolfo Lopes Gomes                              
Adriano Leonel Fernandes Castro Goncalves              
Agostinho Alberto Pereira Duarte                       
Agostinho Fernando Nogueira Pereira                    
Aires Manuel Oliveira da Costa                         
Alberto Costa                                          
Alberto Sergio Oliveira Dias Silva                     
Albino Mouta de Sousa                                  
Alfredo de Sousa Barreto                               
Alfredo Guilherme Gonçalves Cerqueira                  
Alfredo Magalhães Queiros                              
Alfredo Miguel Pereira Goncalves Vieira da Silva
```

I need the output like this, only the fist and last name!

```
Abel Barros
Abel Dias
Abilio Costa
Adelino Silva
Ademar Gomes
Adriano Gonçalves
Agostinho Duarte
...
```

How can i do this in MS SQL 2016

Thanks on advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?????

Comment: HINT: LEFT, CHARINDEX, REVERSE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using left, right and charindex

```
 SELECT LEFT(your_col, charindex(' ', your_col) - 1) , 
       RIGHT(your_col, CHARINDEX (' ' ,REVERSE(your_col))-1)
from your_table
```

Comment: We may need some checks in case if there are a single words(without any spaces) or NULL values:
SELECT 
 IIF(charindex(' ', @your_col) > 0, LEFT(@your_col, CHARINDEX(' ', @your_col) - 1), @your_col), 
    IIF(charindex(' ', @your_col) > 0, RIGHT(@your_col, CHARINDEX (' ' ,REVERSE(@your_col))-1), NULL)
from your_table

Comment: thanks for your help! I have need to make some adjustment to the this query work! rtrim to the field

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following.

First split string before the space separator

```
SUBSTRING(Nome, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Nome))
```

Then split string at the last occurence

```
SUBSTRING( Nome , LEN(Nome) -  CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Nome)) + 2  , LEN(Nome))
```

Concatenate both with the following `+ ' ' +`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Nome, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Nome)) + ' ' +
SUBSTRING( Nome , LEN(Nome) -  CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Nome)) + 2  , LEN(Nome)  )
FROM table1;
```

Test here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f54391/1

Answer (score 0):

Just in case other see this and needs SQL Server 2008 (or older).

You can modify the answer from scaisEdge to take care of single word-names, without using [IIF (introduced in SQL Server 2012)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql)

Simply add a space after name, when looking for first name, and add a space before name when looking for last name. 
replace co.Name with your actual column name.

```
LEFT(co.Name, charindex(' ', co.Name+' ') - 1) firstname, 
RIGHT(co.Name, CHARINDEX (' ' ,REVERSE(' ' + co.Name))-1) lastname,
```